# Move source files in KDevelop4

Tags: c++, c, kdevelop4

This may sounds a little trivial but I really dont get it.

The [ProjectView](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/KDevelop_4_Screenshot.png) (Left side of the screen) displays all files of your project. You are able to create and delete files but you can't move files to different folders (I'm familar with MSVC).

Is there a way of moving source files in Kdevelop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag and drop support for moving files has been implemented for quite some time.

In KDevelop 4.5 (currently master) there will be more options like described here: http://nikosams.blogspot.co.at/2012/10/kdevelop-project-and-filesystem-view.html

Answer (score 1):

I wonder the same thing-- I always manually create a new 'src' folder and manually move the source files into the new folder. Then I edit the cmake file to compile the sources in the src folder.